# Environment to use locally the Skeetch font

Tags: fonts, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

For pedagogical reasons, I would like to produce exercises using a text displayed like if it was written by hand.

The following LaTeX font looks good for me : http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/skeetch/ .

My problem is to define one environment to use locally this font on one Mac OS that uses TeX Live. How can I do that?

Comment: Here's a similar, *somewhat*  prominent question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-an-cthulhu-worshipping-mad

Comment: Since you mention "[writing] the statement and use a scanner", consider reading [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32940/5764).

Comment: @Werner : Thanks for the link but I've indicated that's not a solution for me.

Comment: Does the [LaTeX Font Catalogue on Calligraphic and Handwritten fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html) help?

Comment: I've forgotten this, I'm a little stupid sometimes... Yes, I've found Skeetch but I've another problem. I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

not entirely trivial, since tex live doesn't have the emerald font set.
(i don't know why, but solving it doesn't get your job done very quickly.

however, if you're willing to download the package from ctan and put the files where they're needed (cf. https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf), the font catalogue's example source link should provide all you need.