# Writing an official letter

Tags: letters

I want to write an official letter such as apply for fund ... as following :

> > `To`
> >
> > `Subject`
> >
> > `Body`
> >
> > `Sign`
> >
> > `Name`

I would appreciate if you can tell me the proper packages I should use for that.

Comment: What about the letter class? This is part of standard LaTeX. Please see at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letter if you want to know more. You may want to see the al­ter­na­tive LaTeX class(es) at the bottom if it does not suit you.

Comment: Do you know KOMA-Script and the documentclass `scrlttr2`? You can set foldermarks, footer etc. See `texdoc KOMA-Script` (with examples!).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For an official letter it can't do any harm to use a dedicated class which will do the general formatting. One of those classes is `scrlttr2` from the »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« bundle. Although this class is very flexible (and thus quite complex), you can get quick and good results with basic settings like in this approach.

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  parskip=half,
  enlargefirstpage=on,    % More space on first page
  fromalign=right,        % PLacement of name in letter head
  fromphone=on,           % Turn on phone number of sender
  fromrule=aftername,     % Rule after sender name in letter head
  addrfield=on,           % Adress field for envelope with window
  backaddress=on,         % Sender address in this window
  subject=beforeopening,  % Placement of subject
  locfield=narrow,        % Additional field for sender
  foldmarks=on,           % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily \LARGE}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{From Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{From Street\\00000 From City}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 0000 0\,00\,00\,00}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace}
\setkomavar{signature}{(From Name)}
\setkomavar{place}{From City}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{To Name\\To Street\\00000 To Place}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
    \opening{Ladies and Gentlemen,}

    \blindtext

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

For details about the many options for customization please refer to the »[KOMA-Script](http://texdoc.net/pkg/koma-script)« user guide. You may also want to take a look at »[newlfm](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm)«.

---

[image]

Answer (score 32):

You don't need anything fancy here - the standard `article` class will do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\begin{document}
\hspace*{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
Random Institute \par
Random City 1000 \par
Randomia \par
\today
\end{minipage}

To whom it may concern: \par \bigskip

Hire me, it'll be worth your while. \par \bigskip

Sincerely, \par \medskip

\includegraphics[height=1.5\baselineskip]{signature} \par
Random Randofsky \par
Randomville
\end{document}
```

I wouldn't recommend the `letter` class, since it requires a specific structure that is very rigid. Next thing you know you'll want to re-order the layout, which requires very little interference when dealing with `article`.

For a way to include an actual signature in your letter, see [Adding a signature on an online job application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764).

Comment: You might want to add a `\setpagestyle{empty}` to that for a single-page letter.

Comment: Can I ask what font was used for the signature ?

Comment: @SohaibAfifi: I wrote it on a piece of paper (by hand), scanned it and used [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/en/)'s tracing capabilities to vectorize the scanned bitmap image, then exported it as an EPS or PDF (whichever you prefer), and included it in my document using `\includegraphics`. See [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764) for a step-by-step description of the procedure from the command-line (and using [`potrace`](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: @Werner Is there a way to add a space between the end of the minipage and the actual letter? It seems a bit bunched up to me.

Comment: @lpnorm: Sure! Add `\bigskip`, or something more verbose, like `\vspace{2\baselineskip}` to insert a gap equivalent to 2 lines of text. In general, `\vspace{<len>}` should work (where you specify any `<len>`). Note that you need to be in vertical mode for that, so either issue an explicit `\par` before it, or leave a blank line.