# Packages for writing Letter

Tags: packages, letters

I am looking for packages to write letters. The packages should be able to understand the German <s>`DIN1338{a,b}`</s> letter format.

What are common packages which are still maintained?

I meant `DIN 5008` [Din 5008](http://www.search-document.com/pdf/3/1/din-5008.html), [Changes to DIN 676](http://www.search-document.com/pdf/3/1/din-676.html)

[edit] See also my other post and my issues with [Dinbrief](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155682/dinbrief-and-pagenumbers)

However `dinbrief` is quite old, and I am unable to do line numbering or
AFAIR tables. That is the reason why I ask for alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at the KOMA letter class.

Comment: BTW: DIN 1338 specifies mathematical typesetting ("Formelsatz"),so  you probably mean DIN 676a and 676b, respectively.

Comment: The `article` class works for letters as well.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133836).

Comment: @Daniel: I meant 5008, if 676 is a successor then I'll modify my question again. KOMA, Ok, perhaps too hard to learn.

Comment: @Werner: uhh, agree, but still too much work.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: I saw it already. Thanks anyways.

Comment: In which way is there much to learn for the use of »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« in comparison to other approaches?

Comment: @bersch: Your links don't work for me, guess they need a cookie only available on your machine. Nevertheless, regarding layout and everything else provided by the class DIN 676 is still fully compatible with DIN 5008.

Comment: @Daniel: no cookies required.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: I've been using dinbrief and have some issues with it. It'd documentation is shorter,than KOMA :-) (I prepare a separate post on this topic.)

Comment: I do only know, that it exists. So take a look on documentation for your own: `g-brief` (probably better is `g-brief2`).

Comment: I'd consider »[dinbrief](http://ctan.org/pkg/dinbrief)« obsolete (as well as »[g-brief](http://ctan.org/pkg/g-brief)«).

Comment: @Thorsten Donig: So you mean there are no alternatives? At least could you explain why you consider "dinbrief" and "g-brief" obsolete?

Comment: I didn't say that there are no alternatives. Au contraire. There are many [classes and packages for writing a letter](http://ctan.org/topic/letter). But »dinbrief« and »g-brief« are very inflexible and from the dates of last revision in their manuals you can see that they are effectively unmaintained.

Comment: Well, because the are not touched could also be a reason for completed final version. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usally use the [`dinbrief`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dinbrief) document class. I don't know if it is still maintained, but the last update is from 2000. It does, however, what I need. I haven't used `scrlttr2` yet so I cannot compare them.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\briefkopf{\raggedleft{Karl Putt\\ Bahnhofstr. 3\\ 01010 Irgendwo}}

\begin{document}
\subject{Benötigte Unterlagen}
\backaddress{Karl Putt, Bahnhofstr. 3, 01010 Irgendwo}
\nowindowrules
\signature{Karl Putt}
\Datum{\today}
\address{\briefkopf}

\begin{letter}{Max Mustermann \\ %
                Institut für Muster \\ %
                Parkstr. 8 \\ \\ 10115 Berlin
 }
    \opening{Sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann,}
    \blindtext[1]

    \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image: letter]

Comment: I think mixing `babel` and `xelatex` is not a great idea. There is `polyglossia` out there.

Comment: @Manuel: Why should that be a bad idea? The »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)« package is prepared for XeTeX and LuaTeX and will be improved in this regard. → See: [polyglossia vs babel](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88481)

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Many answers like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3000/21930) usually recommend using `polyglossia` instead. I thought that `babel` was incompatible with `xelatex`, but as you point out, it's not. Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

The [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) letter class `scrlttr2` is very customizable and provides support for DIN 676/5008 out of the box (p. 195):

> `DIN` parameter set for letters on A4-size paper, complying with German standard DIN 676; suitable for window envelopes in the sizes C4, C5, C6, and C6/5 (C6 long).
>
> `DINmtext`
> parameter set for letters on A4-size paper, complying with DIN 676, but using an alternate layout with more text on the first page; only suitable for window envelopes in the sizes C6 and C6/5 (C6 long).

(Even though DIN 676 has been superseded by DIN 5008 in 2011, the regulations for the layout of business letters have almost kept the same, only one dimension has been relaxed a bit. Hence, the DIN 676 layout adheres to DIN 5008.)

Parameter sets are simply passed as options to the class. The following shows a minimalistic letter:

```
\documentclass[version=last,DIN]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{letter}{%
  Joana Public\\ 
  Hillside 1\\ 
  12345 Public-City%
} 
  \opening{Dear chairman,} 
  the last general meeting was about one year ago. 
  I want to remind you, that the constitution of our club advises you to make a general meeting every six month. 
  Because of this I expect the executive board to detain such a meeting immediately. 
  \closing{Expecting an invitation} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, the `DIN` settings are even loaded as a default, so it is not necessary to pass them explicitly. For further customizations, please take a look into the [Manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), which is available in German and English.

Only available in German is the extended manual as a [printed book](http://www.amazon.de/KOMA-Script-Anleitung-Sammlung-Klassen-Paketen/dp/3865412912), which is supposed to provide specifically more customization examples for the letter class.

Comment: Instead of page number (differs very likely from language to language) give better the chapter numbers (more stable) in documentation and the KOMA-Script version, where it is valid. So, chapters 4 and 21 in version 3.12.