# Need a latex template for letter in format with from and to one after another and followed by body of letter

Tags: templates, letters

I like to type a letter in latex with From and To one after another and then followed by sub and then body of letter. unable to set the From and To in the page. Suggest me how to put it shall i use mini box.

Comment: You can find some templates for letters in [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/formal-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is useful:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\pagestyle{empty}%%In case the page numbers are not necessary
\begin{document}
From\\
abcd\\
cdefg\\
hijkl\\

\vskip 12pt
To\\
xyz\\
12345\\
LKJH\\

\vskip 24pt
Sub: Here goes my subject\\

\vskip 24pt
Dear xyz,\\

Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here Some text here Some text here


\flushright{Sincerely,}
\flushright{abcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another one with a pre-defined environment:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\pagestyle{empty}%%In case the page numbers are not necessary
\begin{document}

\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}

\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear abc}
\dots
\closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes ps.}
\encl{Enclosures}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are also many commands like \opening, \closing, \ps, \signature, \encl which you can use within the  \begin{letter} ...\end{letter} environment.

Comment: Perhaps you should check this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133836/writing-an-official-letter