# Start letter at the top of the page

Tags: letters

How can I make a letter start at the top of the page rather than the usual vertical spacing ?  I am finding that the `letter` class requires a specific structure that is very rigid.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}

\title{The deterioration of Health and safety}
\author{Heime}
\date{January 2023}

\signature{Heime}

\address{This and That}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Alice}
  \opening{Something}

  \begin{flushright}
    \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
    \signature{Heime}
  \end{flushright}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[vscale=0.9]{geometry}`? Or whatever proportion you want to use.

Comment: I won't recommend using the `letter` class. See [Writing an official letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133840/5764) on how to write a letter using the default `article` class.

Comment: Looking at letter.cls, it is dificult to tell where the space is defined (unlike \@makechapterhead).  The space decreases if the letter is longer, but only to a point.

Comment: Have thought about using article actually.  I think I would have better control upon the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,fromalign=right,refline=nodate,backaddress=false,addrfield=topaligned,foldmarks=false]{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{signature}{Heime}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{This and That}
\setkomavar{date}{January 2023}

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft\usekomavar{date}}% put the date into the
                                % location field
\setplength{locvpos}{\topmargin+1in+\headheight+\headsep+1.2\baselineskip}% move the location field

\setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}% limit the width of the head at the
                                % notepaper to the paper width

\setplength{toaddrhpos}{\oddsidemargin+1in}% possition of the recipient address
\setplength{toaddrvpos}{\topmargin+1in+\headheight+\headsep}

\setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}+\useplength{toaddrheight}}% possition of the reference line

\setplength{sigindent}{.5\textwidth}% possition of the signature
\let\raggedsignature=\raggedright

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Alice}
  \opening{Something}
  \lipsum[1]
  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information about using `scrlttr2` (or package `scrletter`, e.g., in combination with class `scrartcl`) see chapters 4 and 21 in the KOMA-Script manuals and maybe also “[How to create letters with KOMA-Script](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_Letter/)” (also available [in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_Letter/)).

Comment: The letter style looks quite complicated to configure differently.

Comment: @Ragonese Only because it provides lots of features to be less rigid, but very flexible. ;-)