# Include signature picture in cover letter in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I created a cover letter with the moderncv package. My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2013]{moderntimeline}

% New page style
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\sffamily\footnotesize
 Teest\\Test}}
\fancyhead[C]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\fixedphonesymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  213123312}}
\fancyhead[R]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\emailsymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  test@test.com}}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\let\ps@empty\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myfancy}

% Redefinitions of \makecvtitle, opening and closing to
% have the desired formatting for first and family names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname}\par\smallskip\namestyle{\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries\@firstname\\\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname\\\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother


% for timeline

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}
}
\newcommand\tllabelcventryn[9][color1]{%
  \gdef\Argi{#1}%
  \gdef\Argii{#2}%
  \gdef\Argiii{#3}%
  \gdef\Argiv{#4}%
  \gdef\Argv{#5}%
  \gdef\Argvi{#6}%
  \gdef\Argvii{#7}%
  \gdef\Argviii{#8}%
  \gdef\Argix{#9}%
  \auxtllabelcventryn
}
\def\auxtllabelcventryn#1{%
  \gdef\Argx{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{ifthenelse(\Argiii==0,\tl@lastyear,\Argiii)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(\Argii-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\Argi] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,anchor=north east] {\Argiv} node [tl@startyear,above] {\Argv}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt);
     \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\Argiii} \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt
        \shade [left color=\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{\Argvi}{\Argvii}{\Argviii}{\Argix}{\Argx}%
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{Ctest}
\familyname{test}
\title{Curriculum vit\ae{}}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}

\recipient{Test}{Test\\Test} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Commitee Members:} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,} 
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} 

\makelettertitle 
Text a lot of text.
\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: te]
Now I want to include my handwritten signature under the sincerely yours and above my name. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `\closing{Sincerely yours,\\\includegraphics{signature}}`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks, but this does not work. It just vanishes, so if I use your command instead of \makeletterclosing the signature just disappears. 

(One further note in general: I want to have my prename and surname additionally printed below the handwritten signature.)

Answer (score 14):

I would follow the procedure listed in [Adding a signature on an online job application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764) to obtain an electronic (vectorized) version of a signature. Assume the signature is called `signature.pdf`. Then you would add the following code to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  \includegraphics{signature}\\% Insert signature
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother
```

The above redefinition of `\makeletterclosing` merely inserts `\includegraphics{signature}\\` before printing the first/last name. You may want to reduce the space after the closing and the beginning of the signature (currently listed above as `3em`).

Comment: I would suggest two changes. First is to remove (or reduce) the `\\[3em]` to reduce the spacing between the closing and the signature file. Second is to include the optional `[height=3em]` to the `includegraphics` statement to ensure that the signature is a good height no matter how big the actual file is.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there's no need to use the macro Daniel suggested, although it works. Here is something more simple that also allows you to adjust the signature size and reduce the vertical space after it. I used:

```
\closing{Sincerely yours,\\ \includegraphics[width=4cm]{pictures/Signature} \vspace{-1cm}}
```

In case you need to adjust the horizontal positioning of your signature as well, use something like

```
\closing{Sincerely yours,\\ \hbox{\hspace{-0.6cm} \includegraphics[width=4cm]{pictures/Signature}} \vspace{-1cm}}
```

Comment: Note that the `\vspace` is not executed with the `\closing`...

Answer (score 5):

My Solution is this:

```
\closing{Mit freundlichem Gruß, }
\vspace{-6em}
\includegraphics[height=3em]{signature.png}
\vspace{6em}
```

basically I put the hand written sig below the name but push it up between the two texts. It's not "good" but it works quickly and without issues. So it's a good enough fix for a small project like a letter to me.

Answer (score -1):

It can work like this,

```
\signature{\includegraphics[height=.7in]{Signature.png} \\ Your Name}
```

This is one of the simple and easy trick.