# Adding a EPS file to a cover letter created by newlfm package

Tags: eps, newlfm

I am working on a cover letter provided by latextemplates.com that uses newlfm package:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter

I would like to add my signature (as a EPS) file to the end of the letter, just above my name. Has anyone had experience with that? I would appreciate your help.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

%\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.0in}{\vspace{0.5in}
\includegraphics[width=1.5 \linewidth]{mac.eps}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page
\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=0pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{My name} % Name

\addrfrom{ 
\today\\[12pt] % Date
address
}

\phonefrom{(345345} % Phone number

\emailfrom{email@trc.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours, \\\includegraphics[width=0.5 \linewidth]{sign.eps}}

\nameto{Mrs. Jane Smith} % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
The Corporation \\
123 Pleasant Lane \\
City, State 12345
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%   LETTER CONTENT

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Related: [Include signature picture in cover letter in `moderncv`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134540/5764); [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764)

Comment: I use \closeline{Sincerely yours, \\\includegraphics[width=0.5 \linewidth]{sign.eps}},  It inserts the signiture and gives me the output, but there is an error at begin{newlfm}.

Comment: Please provide an example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not caused by the graphics; the problem is the line break in the argument to `\closeline`. Simply using `\newline` in place of `\\` resolves the issue.

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\begin{document}
\closeline{Sincerely yours, \newline 123 } % but not \\ in place of \newline
\begin{newlfm}
ABC
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```