# Creating Logo with Fancy Font

Tags: fonts, graphics, logos

I am trying to creating a logo that resembles this one shown below, but I do not know the best way of going about it. I know of a fonts package that may be useful, but not sure how to overlay the letters on top of each as so. Would anyone know a neat way of accomplishing this?

Picture of Logo:

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary that you create this using LaTeX/TikZ? Or is using Inkscape or Illustrator also an option?

Comment: –1: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @BartArondson: No, not any particulars. I did not know the best way to overlay text on each like so, but I was aware of the `Tikz` and `pstricks` but have not yet got to fully exploit those packages to put together anything comprehensive.

Comment: @Tobi: Thank You for the input. I do know about a `MWE` but did not come up with anything that would work. I knew the route to go but no idea how to correctly start.

Comment: It is always preferred to tell (at least) what you’ve tried yet. Otherwise it’s just a “do it for me” question which are not very welcome here (and everywhere else, too …)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an easy job with `tikz`. Change colors and glyphs by yourself to suit your needs. (I am bad in their selection ;-)...)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \path[fill=Brown4!30!DarkBlue] (0,0) circle (1.17cm);
   \path[fill=blue!50!black!10] (0,0) circle (1.05cm and 1.1cm);
   \node[text=Brown4!30!DarkBlue,scale=3.5] at (-0.4,0.25) {R};
   \node[text=Brown4!30!DarkBlue,scale=3.5] at (0.25,-0.25) {T};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it looks lovely!  Where did you find that font face?

Comment: @SeanAllred That is the font hated by many - `Zapf Chancery` :-)

Comment: I like it for decorative purposes like this, but it does seem like it would be a bad font for body text… too fancy :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred That is my feeling too. That is why the above comment :-)

Comment: Looks great Harrish. This will be a nice example to learn from as I am looking to learn more about the `tikz` package. Thank You.

Comment: @nightowl: If you wan't to learn TikZ I suggest starting with the tutorial in the manual (pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 14):

If you have the glyphs that make up the components,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{calc}% To make up for omission from stackengine V3.22
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{-.6ex}{c}{+.45ex}{\small\itshape R}{%
\stackinset{c}{+.3ex}{c}{-.45ex}{\small\itshape T}{%
\Huge\hstretch{1.2}{$O$}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Once you have the look you like, you can `\scalebox` it to whatever size you need (`graphicx` package required).

Comment: Very unique solution. I like the conciseness and the non manual longevity of inputting all specific information in piece by piece. Also, `+1` for the nonchalant manner of using `"promoting"` :) your own built package (hehehe). You found a useful way to employ your package to a neat little example.

Comment: Interesting, where exactly would you place `\scalebox` if one did want to enlarge the logo? I tried, but it seemed to eject the letters from within its circle.

Comment: @nightowl basically, the complete document, from right after `\begin{document}` to right before `\end{document}` should be enclosed in the `\scalebox` to enlarge the image.

Answer (score 13):

This is super-easy when you use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), which employs the [Potrace bitmap tracing engine](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) (also used for [signature conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764)).

1. Import the bitmap into Inkscape (I made a screen grab of the image):

   [image]
2. With the image selected, click Path > Trace Bitmap. Without changing any settings, click OK:

   [image]
3. The image is now vectorized. You're only left to match the colours using the tools provided:

   [image]
4. Save as PDF (or other vector format):

   [image]

Comment: How do you match the colours?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Inkscape has a "dropper" tool (left vertical toolbar, second from the bottom in my screen shot). Alternatively, I use a similar tool in Windows's Paint. Darker blue is RGB = [34;33;96], inner light blue is RGB = [239;239;247].