# crop a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

My purpose is to create a table of numbers in a fancy font. My approach is based on `tikzpicture`: I plan to first generate a bunch of images of the numbers I want and later insert them into a master document with `\includegraphics`

At this time my images have too much whitespace. This problem has come up before on tex.stackexchange, but I haven't been able to make the proposed solutions work in this case. Here is what I am getting:

[image]

This is based on a suggestion found here:

[Creating Logo with Fancy Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145061/creating-logo-with-fancy-font)

and this is the code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text=Brown4!30!DarkBlue,scale=50]{1};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

I set the `inner sep` and `outer sep`  to `0pt`, but that does not appear to be enough.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: I still thing that standalone only cuts to where no "points" are placed, even though they are invisible. An easy solution is to use Imagemagick to further crop it: `convert -trim [-density 300|400] in.png out.png`

Comment: Thanks zeroth! I have imagemagick and also have command-line solutions involving pdfcrop and also based on postscript and ghostscript, but I was looking for a tikzpicture solution, if there is one.

Comment: I think the problem is with the font itself. You are not drawing it with TiKZ. In fact if you add `draw` to your node will see that standalone crops it correctly.

Comment: Why not typesetting the character directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by ignasi, the problem is with the font itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}%
\fboxsep=0pt
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont%
\fbox{1}
\end{document}%
```

Produces this:

[image]

Compare above with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}%
\fboxsep=0pt
%\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont%
\fbox{1}
\end{document}%
```

[image]

There is always space on left and right of `1`. This tells us that `standalone` is doing good job in cutting the borders and the space left empty is not the border actually.

Hence your best bet will be to use `imagemagick`. Now the question is making the process automatic. You have two ways: 1. do it from within the `.tex` file, and 2. use a batch (`.bat` for windows) file:

## From within the `.tex` file

(Compile this with `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{1.tex}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text=Brown4!30!DarkBlue,scale=50]{1};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
\end{filecontents*}
%%
%% Produce pdf file
\immediate\write18{pdflatex 1}
%%
%% get png file from pdf
\immediate\write18{convert -density 300 -alpha on 1.pdf 1.png}
%%
%% crop the png file
\immediate\write18{convert -trim  1.png 1-trimmed.png}
%
\begin{document}
  See the same folder as this file.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The batch file:

Save the following as a file `mytrim.bat`:

```
@ECHO ON
cls
REM ECHO.

REM convert pdf to png

CD /D %~dp0
SET Program="convert.exe"
REM convert pdf to png
for %%A in (*.pdf) do %Program%  -density 300 -alpha on %%A %%~nA.png
mkdir pngs
REM convert png to trimmed png
for %%A in (*.png) do %Program%  -trim %%A pngs/%%~nA-trimmed.png
REM delete temporary un-trimmed png files
del *.png
Pause
```

First produce all numbers in pdf form in a folder. Put `mytrim.bat` in the same folder and double click on it. A new folder named `pngs` will be created which would contain trimmed `png` files.

Comment: this is ever so thorough and I am most grateful!

Comment: sorry to bother you, now that I'm in front of my computer again I have a question: how do you run the .tex solution? (latex, pdflatex, something else?)

Comment: I tried latex and pdflatex with shell-escape, but I get `runsystem(pdflatex 1)...disabled (restricted)` in the `log` file. (I have no problem with the .bat file on Windows) I'm on Mac OSX, I installed imagemagick from `http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/`. Any ideas? Should I post a separate question?

Comment: @PatrickT Sorry for the delay. I used `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`. It needs shell escape (or `write18`). I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Harish, I suspect my texlive is not speaking to imagemagick, but no worries I have it set up on Windows, just need to switch machines. Thanks very much!

Comment: @PatrickT Oho. I have no idea. It should have worked on texlive too. Glad that it worked on windows. I think it is the easiest. :)

Comment: It works with TexShop on Mac OS X, so it's something I need to fix in TexStudio on the Mac. Cheers Harish.

Comment: @PatrickT You can convert those png's back in to pdf isn't it? Also play with the parameters like density in the .bat file.

Answer (score 10):

If I understood correctly, clipping seems to work:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\clip (-2.45,0) rectangle (3.75,10.25);
\node[anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,text=Brown4!30!DarkBlue,scale=50]{1};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I guess that he wants an automatic way since he will make similar to other numbers. In your case a manual setup would be necessary.

Comment: @user44524, this is not a bad answer at all and I'm upvoting, as I hadn't been able to make \clip work, so your solution will prove useful no doubt, thanks!