# Someone can help me draw this

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to draw the symbol of my engineering and be able to change the color, anyone can help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Just use Inkscape and export to TikZ.

Comment: Follow the instructions in [Creating Logo with Fancy Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145227/5764).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I know this is sort of policy here, and I’m not entirely opposed to it, but now this leaves this question of questionable quality with a score of +3, which seems undeserved to me. Not sure how to handle issues like this, though.

Comment: @doncherry: well, it has 6 downvotes and 9 upvotes, some of them certainly originated from the _enthusiasm_ of the moment (in upvoting a too much downvoted question and viceversa). I don't have clues as well about how to handle this and to some extent I agree with you that this may not deserve upvotes as _research_ question. Why don't you ask a question on Meta (good period this for these tricky questions, see also percusse's one)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run with `xelatex` and change the colors to whatever you need:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\colorlet{Yellow}{yellow}
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{pspicture}%[showgrid=top]
  (7,10)
\psframe*[linecolor=magenta!60!black!90](7,10)
\psset{linecolor=Yellow}
\pscircle*(3.5,9){0.5}
\rput(5,7.75){\textcolor{Yellow}{\psscalebox{7}{\bfseries e}}}
\psset{linewidth=5mm}
\psline[arrowlength=0.5,arrowsize=0pt 6,arrowinset=0]{->}(3.5,8.2)(3.5,5)
\psline(2,4.75)(5,4.75)
\psline(1.75,3.75)(2.75,3.75)(3.5,4.75)
\psline(3.5,4.75)(3.5,2.5)
\rput(3.5,1.75){\textcolor{Yellow}{\psscalebox{3}{\bfseries Ingeniería}}}
\rput(3.5,0.75){\textcolor{Yellow}{\psscalebox{3}{\bfseries Electrónica}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[magenta!60!black!90](-3.8,-5.5) rectangle (3.8,6);
  \node[fill=yellow,circle,inner sep=12pt,outer sep=5pt] (a) at (0,5) {};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=yellow,scale=6,font=\fontsize{24}{0pt}\bfseries] (b) at (0,-1) 
      {\phantom{a}};
  \draw[line width=16pt,yellow,] (a.south) -- ([yshift=2em]b.north);
  \fill[yellow] ([shift={(-1em,4em)}]b.north west) -- ([shift={(1em,4em)}]b.north east) --
      ([yshift=8pt]b.north) -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=16pt,yellow] ([xshift=-1em]b.north west) -- ([xshift=1em]b.north east);
  \draw[line width=16pt,yellow] (b.north) -- (b.south);
  \draw[line width=16pt,yellow] ([shift={(-1.5em,0.75em)}]b.west) -- ++(2.5em,0) -- 
       ([yshift=-3pt]b.north);
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=yellow,scale=7,font=\bfseries,anchor=south]  at (1.4,3)
      {e};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=yellow,scale=3,font=\bfseries]  at (0,-3.4)
      {Ingeniería};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text=yellow,scale=3,font=\bfseries]  at (0,-4.6)
      {Electrónica};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]