# Color in pstricks not showing

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I'm compiling this [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85863/is-there-is-a-package-so-you-can-add-text-with-visual-effects-like-wordart-fro) with xelatex, I don't get any compilation errors, but the texts are all big black regular ones without any style applied. I'm using TexLive 2013 by the way. How should the file be compiled?

Comment: Compile with LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf...? *That* works for me.

Comment: @Werner Yes, I can get the correct result with LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf. However my document contains other eps/jpg/pdf figures and CJK characters so I need the xelatex part. Any ideas? And maybe it's not colors per se, because I can compile correctly this MWE just fine with xelatex. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179004/someone-can-help-me-draw-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-light3d}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% Or \usepackage[crop=off]{...} for Win without Perl
\begin{document}
...
```

and then run `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` or alternative `lualatex`. The `dvipdfmx` driver of `XeTeX` cannot handle outline fonts.

Comment: It really needs to be on the roadmap of `dvipdfmx`, though. For people who need unicode supprt, this is a mess.

Comment: Why? You can use `lualatex`