# Is there a CD icon/symbol for latex?

Tags: symbols

Is there a CD icon / symbol for LaTeX? I was looking through the whole [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) but haven't found any.

I'm after something like this:  or [this](https://icons8.com/icon/1444/cd).

Comment: If you can't find one in a package, I would just follow my approach here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359, scaling a selected image to some convenient measure of text height.

Comment: fontawesome has added new symbols since the last edition of TCLSL came out, but I couldn't find anything disk related.  Try clip art.

Comment: What about directly using  with a unicode-aware TeX-engine, _i.e._ LuaTeX or XeTeX, and an appropriate font?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simple icons, I would also use Ti*k*Z to draw my own icon (e.g. modelled on your link).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\disc}{{\tikz[baseline=-.75ex]{%
\draw[line width=.1ex] (0,0) circle(.8ex);
\draw[line width=.2ex] (0,0) circle(.2ex);
\draw[line width=.15ex] ([shift=(270:.5ex)]0,0) arc (270:340:.5ex);
\draw[line width=.15ex] ([shift=(90:.5ex)]0,0) arc (90:160:.5ex);
}}}

\begin{document}

Billie Holiday, {\it Body and Soul}, Verve Records \disc

\Large {\it Body and Soul} (1957) \disc

\footnotesize Billie Holiday, {\it Body and Soul} (1957) \disc

\tiny Billie Holiday, {\it Body and Soul} (1957), Verve Records \disc

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

*Completely* impractical:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=45]
\begin{scope}
\clip circle [radius=0.25] [rounded corners=1cm] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill [gray!10] circle [radius=1];
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}\foreach \r in {45, 135}
  \fill [white, opacity=0.1, rotate=\r] 
    (-\i:1) arc (-\i:\i:1) -- (180+\i:1) arc (180+\i:180-\i:1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip circle [radius=0.3] [rounded corners=0.95cm] 
  (-.95,-.95) rectangle (.95,.95);
\fill [gray!20] circle [radius=1];
\foreach \i in {0,...,50}
  \fill [white, opacity=0.05, rotate=90] 
    (-\i:1) arc (-\i:\i:1) -- (180+\i:1) arc (180+\i:180-\i:1) -- cycle;
\foreach \i in {0,0.5, ..., 10}
  \foreach \c [count=\j from -4, evaluate={\a=\j*5-\i; \b=\j*5+5+\i;}] in
    {gray!50!white, red, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, gray!50!white}
      \fill [fill=\c!50, opacity=0.05] 
        (0:0) -- (\a:1) arc (\a:\b:1) -- (\b+180:1) arc (\b+180:\a+180:1) -- (0:0);
\foreach \i in {0,1, ..., 10}
  \foreach \c [count=\j from 16, evaluate={\a=\j*5-\i; \b=\j*5+5+\i;}] in
    {gray!25, white, white, white, gray!25}
      \fill [fill=\c, opacity=0.1] 
        (0:0) -- (\a:1) arc (\a:\b:1) -- (\b+180:1) arc (\b+180:\a+180:1) -- (0:0);
\fill [white, opacity=0.5] circle [radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...but super lovely :D

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

Now without packages except for color (obviously optional):

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1em}
\newcommand\CD[1][black]{{\color{#1!50!black}\begin{picture}(1,1)
\put(.5,.35){\circle{1}}
\put(.5,.35){\circle{.4}}
\put(.5,.35){\circle*{.3}}
\end{picture}}}


\begin{document}
CDROM CDROM CDROM CDROM \par
CDROM CDROM CDROM CDROM \par
CDROM \CD\ CDROM \CD\ CDROM \CD\par 
\CD\ CDROM \CD[white] CDROM \CD[cyan] CDROM\par
\CD[blue] CDROM \CD[orange] CDROM \CD[olive] CDROM\par
CDROM CDROM CDROM CDROM \par
CDROM CDROM CDROM CDROM \par
\end{document}
```

A more realistic CD with the same approach:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\unitlength}{.5mm}
\newcommand\CD[1]{
\scalebox{#1}
{\begin{picture}(6,6)
\color{gray}\put(3.1,2.9){\circle*{6}}
\color{gray!50!cyan!30}\put(3,3){\circle*{6}}
\color{olive!20!cyan!25}\put(3,3){\circle*{5}}
\color{magenta!30!cyan!20!}\put(3,3){\circle*{4.5}}
\color{olive!30!cyan!20}\put(3,3){\circle*{3.7}}
\color{blue!30!cyan!20!}\put(3,3){\circle*{3.1}}
\color{gray!50}\put(3,3){\circle{2}}
\color{gray!30}\put(3,3){\circle*{2}}
\color{gray}\put(3,3){\circle{.7}}
\color{white}\put(3,3){\circle*{.7}}
\end{picture}}}
\begin{document}
\CD{10} 
\end{document}
```

**Old poor-man version** (yes, slightly off-center, sharp eyes...)

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\CDROM#1{\scalebox{#1}{\Huge\textcircled{\raisebox{-.5pt}%
{\small$^{\textcircled{\ensuremath\circ}}$}}}}
\begin{document}
\CDROM1  \CDROM{.5} CDROM 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've never seen a CD with an off-centre hole...

Comment: @Werner What now?

Comment: ...perhaps it's just a visual anomaly, but it doesn't seem like the holes are in the middle.

Comment: @Werner  Yes,  I realized that `\raisebox` require some adjustment, but  I was asking you about  the new version using a `picture` environment.

Answer (score 5):

You could built it with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycd}{\tikz{%
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, text width=.8em, fill=black]{};
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, text width=.42em, fill=white]{};
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, text width=.32em, fill=black]{};
\node[circle, inner sep=0pt, text width=.1em, fill=white]{};
}}
\begin{document}

{\LARGE LARGE text: \mycd}

Normal text: \mycd

{\tiny tiny text: \mycd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just download the image version of the link you and include it using [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\disc}[1][]{\includegraphics[height=1.1ex,#1]{disc.png}}

\begin{document}

Billie Holiday, {\itshape Body and Soul}, Verve Records \disc

\Large {\itshape Body and Soul} (1957) \disc

\footnotesize Billie Holiday, {\itshape Body and Soul} (1957) \disc

\tiny Billie Holiday, {\itshape Body and Soul} (1957), Verve Records \disc

\end{document}
```

If you want a higher-quality version (vectorized, like PDF or EPS), you can trace the bitmap using Inkscape. See [Creating Logo with Fancy Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145227/5764).

If you're concerned about material that may be copyrighted, you can search for free alternatives on (say) [OpenClipArt](https://openclipart.org/search/?query=disc).

Answer (score 2):

As @Virgile (above) pointed out in a comment there is a Unicode character ['OPTICAL DISC' U+1F4BF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4bf/index.htm) 💿   Obviously its availability depends on the current font, and requires full Unicode support, such as in XeTeX or LuateX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}

\begin{document}

{\symbola\symbol{"1F4BF}}

\end{document}
```

[image: optical disk icon]

Thanks to @Henri_Menke for extending my comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Not totally serious.*

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
Poor Man's Disc Symbol: \faicon{dot-circle-o} or \faDotCircleO 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> "Any diagram that can be written in PSTricks, will eventually be
>   written in PSTricks."

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle{3}
    \psRing*[linecolor=blue!90](0,0){1}{2.9}
    \psRing*[linecolor=blue!50](0,0)[30,60]{1}{2.9}
    \psRing*[linecolor=blue!50](0,0)[210,240]{1}{2.9}
    \psRing*[linecolor=lightgray]{.9}{.95}
    \psRing*[linecolor=lightgray]{.3}{.35}  
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]