# In ConTeXt, how do I typeset my name like a signature?

Tags: fonts, context, calligraphy

How could I typeset my name so that it appeared in a calligraphic font for use as a signature? I have tried reading the manuals and documentation regarding fonts, but it seems very complex.

Comment: You could print out the document and then write on it with a pen. No calligraphic font is your signature, so it seems dodgy to me to have a pretend signature like this.

Comment: Benjamin, thanks for your helpful comment, but in the specific circumstances I am comfortable with an electronically produced signature. I'd be grateful to hear other suggestions. If it helps, imagine that I'm typesetting a fictional letter in a story book.

Comment: Have a look at [Adding a signature on an online job application](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32911/adding-a-signature-on-an-online-job-application/51560#51560); it is for LaTeX, but I don't see why it shouldn't work for you, too (after a bit of fiddling).

Comment: Pier, thank you for the relevent link. However, it appears to me that the accepted answer focuses on scanning a handwritten copy of your signature, rather than producing one with a calligraphic font, which is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can combine the best of both worlds, and save a few keystrokes, (the font or any font may be downloaded, as long as it's for personal use).

```
\font\signature=ChopinScript at 16truept
\starttext
\input linden
\blank[2*big]
\signature Signature Here
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace your font definition with `\definefont[signature][file:ChopinScript*default]`, this way you can write `style=signature` for all setups which have a `style` key. The `*default` in the definition enables ligatures and kerning for the font which are missing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a calligraphic font with `\definefontfamily` and access it with the `\cg` command.

```
\definefontfamily [signature] [rm] [Latin Modern Roman]
\definefontfamily [signature] [cg] [TeX Gyre Chorus]
\definefontfamily [signature] [mm] [Latin Modern Math]

\setupbodyfont[signature]

\starttext

Richard Parsons

{\cg Richard Parsons}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using a calligraphic font for a signature really solves the problem. After all, each signature is different. A real solution would use a dynamic calligraphic font, if it existed. For the time being however,  you can use Knuth's punk font, if you don't mind its slightly awkward look:

```
\usemodule[punk] 
\usetypescript[punk]
\setupbodyfont[punk,20pt]
\EnableRandomPunk
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\starttext
\dorecurse{5}{Richard Parsons\par}
\stoptext
```

[image]