# How to include utf8 symbols by number?

Tags: unicode

I would like to add utf8 symbol 8962 in pdflatex. So that

```
My code will have \symbol{8962}
```

My text will show  ⌂ .

I am using the compilation sequence `pdflatex biber pdflatex pdflatex`

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? If so, both `\symbol{8962}` and `\char 8962` will work provided you have a font that supports those characters. If not, you need to clarify in your question.

Comment: pdfTeX is limited to 8-bit (0-255) fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution:

```
% Preamble
\newrobustcmd*{\myhome}[1][black]{\tikz{\draw (0,0) -- (0,.15cm) -- (.1cm,.25cm) -- (.2cm,.15cm) -- (0.2cm,0) -- (0,0);}}

% Text
Which is located at \myhome ~ on the map.
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366180/48) for some understanding of different ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In PDFTeX, you need to do this on a case-by-case basis.  Look for your symbol in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), or try detexify.  The packages `textcomp`, `amssymb`, `stix`, `stix2` and `pifont` have particularly large selections of symbols that are also in Unicode.

That particular symbol is available in both `stix` and `stix2` as `\house`.  Although the exact syntax you want conflicts with standard LaTeX, you can also make any arbitrary Unicode character active with `newunicodechar`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[notext]{stix2}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{⌂}{\ensuremath{\house}}

\begin{document}

The ⌂ is an office building, not a house.

\end{document}
```

[image: Stix Two sample]

That example is going to change all your math symbols in a way you might not want, however.  It is possible, through some reverse-engineering, to import only the particular symbols you want, but you might run out of LaTeX math alphabets.

To make the same document body work with Unicode, you could replace most of the preamble with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, which also defines `\house`.  This particular symbol is not present in the default text or math fonts, but you could load it from XITS, Stix Math or Stix Two Math:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={`⌂}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Stix Two Math}
\newunicodechar{⌂}{\ensuremath{\house}}

\begin{document}

The ⌂ is an office building, not a house.

\end{document}
```

[image: unicode-math sample]

An alternative using only `fontspec` is:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\pifamily}{DejaVu Serif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newunicodechar{⌂}{{\pifamily{}⌂}}

\begin{document}

The ⌂ is an office building, not a house.

\end{document}
```

[image: fontspec sample]

Since that would break `⌂` as input in in math mode, you might instead declare the text-mode symbol as `\texthouse`.

Either of the previous two examples allow you to use either plain TeX `\char` or LaTeX `\symbol` with the Unicode code point, in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  PDFLaTeX simply does not support that.