# How to obtain a swiss letter layout?

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I would like to obtain exactly this layout for a letter but I didn't get it up to know.

[image]

I found the classes `chletter` on ctan but after reading the documantation I think it does not allow this date position.

```
\documentclass[]{chletter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\name{My Name}
\address{My Street \\ My city}
\date{The place where I am, \today}
\title{\textbf{The title of the job \quad --\quad 100\%}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Compagny\\Contact person\\Street\\City}
\object
\opening{Dear Mr. Forexample,}
My letter body.
\closing{Best regards}
%\encl{enclosures}
%\cc{other recipients}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

But the result I obtained is the following :
[image]

I also try the class `scrlttr2` but I did not found out yet how to get this layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example using `scrlttr2`:

```
\documentclass[
  SN,% lco file for swiss letters (SN 010 130))
  refline=dateleft,
  firstfoot=false,
  enlargefirstpage,
  backaddress=false,
  foldmarks=false,
  parskip=half-
  ]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street \\ My city}
\setkomavar{date}{The place where I am, \today}
\setkomavar{subject}{The title of the job \quad --\quad 100\%}
\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedright}

\makeatletter
  \@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{Compagny\\Contact person\\Street\\City}
    \opening{Dear Mr. Forexample,}
    \blindtext

    \blindtext
    \closing{Best regards}
    \encl{enclosures}
    \cc{other recipients}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To shift your address a little down add the wanted shift to the pseudolength `firstheadvpos`.

```
    \documentclass[
      SN,% lco file for swiss letters (SN 010 130))
      refline=dateleft,
      firstfoot=false,
      enlargefirstpage,
      backaddress=false,
      foldmarks=false,
      parskip=half-
      ]{scrlttr2}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street \\ My city}
    \setkomavar{date}{The place where I am, \today}
    \setkomavar{subject}{The title of the job \quad --\quad 100\%}
    \setkomafont{title}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedright}

    \makeatletter
      \@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
      \@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{.5cm}% <- shift the head with your address .5cm down
    \makeatother

    \renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}

    \usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
    \begin{document}
      \begin{letter}{Compagny\\Contact person\\Street\\City}
        \opening{Dear Mr. Forexample,}
        \blindtext

        \blindtext
        \closing{Best regards}
        \encl{enclosures}
        \cc{other recipients}
      \end{letter}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you load `visualize.loc` in your preamble you can show the position and size of some fields:

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head,foot,address,location,refline}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @esdd it is even closer to what I want. Any Idea on how to shift only my adresse a little down ?

Comment: @PierrickBersier See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well, have you read the documentation to `chletter` (try `texdoc chletter` on your console/terminal)?

On page 25 you will find chapter "5.5.1 Letterhead layout"  with the definitions you have to change.

Please run the following MWE (and check the additional code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (needed because the code uses `@`)):

```
\documentclass[%
  %leftwin % Adresse Empfänger links, sonst rechts
 %,leftsig
 %,foldmark 
 %,footfill
]{chletter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\makeatletter  % <=====================================================
\if@leftwin
  \def\titletopmatter%
  {\splitfield
   {}{\fromlocation\par\fromname\par\fromaddress\par\telephonenum}}
  \def\titlemidmatter%
  {\returnaddress\par\toname\par\toaddress}
  \def\titlebotmatter%
  {\splitfield
  {\@date}{}} % <===== position of date in letter head!
  \else
  \def\titletopmatter%
  {\splitfield
  {\fromlocation\par\fromname\par\fromaddress\par\telephonenum}{}}
  \def\titlemidmatter%
  {\splitfield
  {}{\returnaddress\par\toname\par\toaddress}}
  \def\titlebotmatter%
  {\splitfield
  {\@date}{}}\fi  % <===== position of date in letter head!
\makeatother  % <=====================================================


\name{My Name}
\address{My Street \\ My city}
\date{The place where I am, \today}
\title{\textbf{The title of the job \quad --\quad 100\%}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Compagny\\Contact person\\Street\\City}
\object
\opening{Dear Mr. Forexample,}
My letter body.
\closing{Best regards}
%\encl{enclosures}
%\cc{other recipients}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and see the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you ! It does the job ! Actually I red the PDF documentation I found with google... But I didn't found out the exact place where to change the position of the date. After I saw your answer it seems pretty obvious...

Answer (score 4):

I have never been in favour of `letter`-like classes. They tend to specify a large amount of settable content in the preamble, making small adjustments to layout very difficult (or cumbersome in the very least).

Letters are easily set inside `article`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}% Remove any headers/footers
\begin{document}
\sffamily% Default font for this letter

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Jean Dupont \\
  Chemin des Capucines 3 \\
  1200 Gen\`eve
\end{tabular}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.5\linewidth}@{}}
  A l'attention de Madame Lara Meier \\
  Chef du personnel \\
  centrale \'electrique de Limmattal \\
  Hagenholzstrasse 74 \\
  8037 Limmattal
\end{tabular}

Gen\`eve, le 20 f\'evrier 2015

\bigskip

\textbf{Candidature pour le poste d'ing\'enieur au sein de votre d\'epartement WORLD}

\bigskip

Madame,

\lipsum[1-3]% Your letter content

Dans l'attente de vos nouvelles, je vous prie de recevoir, Madame, mes salutations les meilleures.

Jean Dupont

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764
\includegraphics[height=3\baselineskip]{example-image}

Annexes: CV, dipl\^omes at certificats de travail

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @werner for you answer. It is really strait forward and easy to do. Actually I chose to do it with the scrlttr2 but the next time I will think about making everything on my own inside of an article.