# Installing Emerald fonts: TeXlive won't find font files

Tags: fonts, texlive

Using TeXlive 2014 I installed the [Emerald fonts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/emerald/) to `~/.texmf` (other TEXMF trees will lead to the same problem).

No matter how much I `texhash` or `updmap`, this minimal example won't complile using `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\begin{document}

\ECFAugie

This is very minimal!

\end{document}
```

I always get the error

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 faumw8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for faumw8r.
mktexpk: perhaps faumw8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file faumw8r): Font faumw8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Using `latex` and `dvips` will yield something similar despite the fact that there is a file `.texmf/fonts/tfm/emerald/faumw8r.tfm`. What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the supplied README (emerald.zip, as available on CTAN)?

Comment: a `tfm` file is a metric file with just the height and width of the letters, you also need to install the actual font file with the letter shapes.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but now you sent me there again, I found the solution. See below. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't follow the instructions in the README file as they are not current and will not ensure that the fonts are generally available to multiple engines.

The following assumes that you have installed the package files successfully. It is strongly recommend to use `TEXMFLOCAL` if you can for this. You can find out where this is using `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL`. Use of your personal `texmf` tree is a distant second-best, and `updmap` rather than `updmap-sys` is not recommended. It will require constant updating - any time you update your TeX installation and changes are made to the fonts installed, you'll need to regenerate your personal map files. Not fun at all. Only consider this if you do not have permission to install to `TEXMFLOCAL`. (And then, ask yourself how badly you really need this font....)

Remove all traces of the package from your personal `texmf` tree and install into the appropriate `TEXMFLOCAL`. Then run `mktexlsr <TEXMFLOCAL>`.

The package provides the type1 versions of the fonts, as well as the support files. There is no need to install fonts additionally.

Double-check that things are installed correctly using e.g. `kpsewhich faumw.pfb`. This should give `<TEXMFLOCAL>/fonts/type1/emerald/faumw.pfb` where `<TEXMFLOCAL>` is the root of the local `texmf` tree you identified above.

If `<TEXMFLOCAL>/web2c/updmap.cfg` exists, you need to edit it. If not, you need to create it. Either way, add the line

```
Map emerald.map
```

Now run `updmap-sys`.

You may need to remove files from your home directory which prevent the system-wide ones having their intended effect. On GNU/Linux, for example, I would remove the directory `~/.texlive2014` where `~` is my home directory and `2014` is the version of TeX Live I'm using. If you are in any doubt, rename the directory rather than removing it.

Then your document should compile just fine:

[image: emerald's Augie]

Incidentally, a version of Augie is available in TeX Live anyway, even without the `emerald` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\augiefamily}{%
  \fontfamily{augie}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaugie}{\augiefamily}

\begin{document}

\augiefamily

This is very minimal!

\end{document}
```

[image: standard Augie]

## EDIT

Admittedly, you can't do this without `emerald`:

[image: emerald sampler]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\begin{document}
  \def\efont{APicture,Augie,Decadence,DecadenceWithoutTheDiamonds,DecadenceCondensed,DecadenceInTheDark,DecadenceInTheDarkCondensed,DecadenceInADifferentLight,DecadenceInTheDarkCondensedMarquee,Intimacy,IntimacyDeux,JD,Movieola,MovieolaTitleType,Pookie,PookieType,Skeetch,SpankysBungalow,SpankysBungalowItalico,SpankysBungalowBlanco,SpankysBungalowBlancoItalico,Syriac,TallPaul,TeenSpirit,Webster}%
  \makeatletter
  \@for \xx:=\efont \do {%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\csname ECF\xx\endcsname This is very minimal\dots\par
  }%
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: `.../texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` is not read by `updmap-sys`, it only reads those in `texmf-config` and `texmf-dist`.

Comment: @Raphael That is not true. At least, it is certainly not true of current TeX Live. It is true that the way this stuff is handled has altered from version to version. Perhaps you have an outdated installation. Or MikTeX, which may do things differently again. But this certainly works for current TeX Live. By default, there is no `updmap.cfg` in `texmf-config` at all. The use of the file in TEXMFLOCAL is documented at the top of the `updmap.cfg` in `texmf-dist/web2c/`, so you can easily confirm what I'm saying if you don't believe me.

Comment: I'm on TeXLive 2015. I can dump you the output of my `updmap-sys` call if you don't believe me. In any case, following your post did not provide me with working fonts. Maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: @Raphael I'm sorry that you are experiencing difficulties, but I can only reiterate that this is currently best practice and it does work. You can also use the `--enable` business, but you lose certain advantages of using the TEXMFLOCAL file. Both options are explained in the comments in the `textmf-dist` `updmap.cfg`. If, after reading that, you continue to have trouble, I can only suggest that you ask a new question saying exactly what you did and exactly what happened.

Comment: @Raphael I haven't tried it, but the existence of `updmap.cfg` in `texmf-config` may be the problem since the instructions do emphasise putting *all* your fonts into the TEXMFLOCAL files. I don't remember exactly, but I think that `updmap-sys` probably only reads one file. So if you created `updmap.cfg` in `texmf-config` previously, perhaps that (counter-intuitively) overrides the file in TEXMFLOCAL.

Comment: The file there if well filled, but I don't recall creating it myself. (Correction: I'm on TeXLive 2014 still. Sorry for the confusion.) Well, thank you; for now, I've answered your parenthetical question in paragraph two and abandoned this quest. I'll try again with a clean installation of the latest TeXLive at some point in the future.

Comment: @cfr hi :). I had problems with TeXLive2015 but solved it by specifying the `updmap.cfg` files myself, as `updmap-sys` did not see the `TEXMFLOCAL` one. See [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307418/)

Comment: I'm facing the exact problem stated by @Raphael and @ Ciprian. Still complaining about missing the package even though I've added them.

Comment: @CroCo That is not nearly enough information to diagnose the problem, as you surely realise.

Comment: @cfr, I've followed your steps literally but still the package is missing. This is with Sierra OS. Adding files inside `/texmf-local/..` is not detected.

Comment: This line `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map emerald.map` solved the problem.

Comment: @CroCo Not the recommended way these days, but certainly not the worst thing to do. The only disadvantage is you'll have to redo it if you update to a new version of TeX Live.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code for augie/JD in texlive, this just saved me from so much pain of manually installing emerald, and IMO this is even a separate answer :-)

Comment: @cfr I'm sorry. I followed the steps without errors. `kpsewhich faumw.pfb` does the correct output but after I put the line in `web2c/updmap.cfg` I still can't compile the example file. From the `updmap-sys` [output](https://gist.github.com/RexYuan/0d665febc64e63485c2785b27b657f6d) (I've put the log in the link too) it looks like it did read `web2c/updmap.cfg`. But I'm still getting the same error as OP (`Font fwbmr8r at 600 not found`) I'm not sure where did it go wrong. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I've also included my texmf folder content in the link. I'm sorry I'm really new to customizing LaTeX and I may have misunderstood something

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand the structure of TeX Live.  I followed the accepted answer above.  I have installed the 2020 version of TeX Live on macos/OSX.  This is the recipe I followed after downloading the `emerald.zip` and expanding the zip file.  As root user in a terminal window:

```
TEXDIR=/usr/local/texlive

EMERALDDIR=/path/to/emerald

mkdir -p ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/fonts/doc/emerald

cp ${EMERALDDIR}/fonts/map/dvips/emerald.map ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/dvips/.


cd ${EMERALDDIR}/tex

tar -cf - latex | (cd ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/tex;tar -xf -)


cd ${EMERALDDIR}/doc

tar -cf - * | (cd ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/fonts/doc/emerald; tar -xf -)

cd ${EMERALDDIR}/fonts

tar -cf - tfm type1 vf | (cd ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/fonts; tar -xf -)


vi ${TEXDIR}/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
  [added "Map emerald.map" line at end of file and saved]


mktexlsr

updmap-sys
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/fonts/emerald/README) apply the instructions given for MikTeX (quite counter-intuitive, eh?) and add

```
Map emerald.map
```

to `.texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` and run `updmap`.

Comment: If you are suggesting doing it this way on TeX Live, it is [A Very Bad Idea](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i). If not, please clarify this.