# Installing the emerald font on TeX Live 2015

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing

I got a new machine and put TeX Live on it, the version you get from tug.org. Now I need to compile a document that uses the [emerald font](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/emerald).

I feel like I have tried everything. The font seems to be there, and `updmap-sys --listmaps` gives me (among other things) `Map emerald.map enabled /home/kristian/tex/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg`.

However, when I try to compile the document, I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `emerald.sty' not found.
```

If I download `emerald.sty` and put it in the directory, the file compiles ... but the font is some kind of replacement. In the file, I call emerald simply with:

```
\usepackage{emerald}
```

What gives? And what should I do? As you may have noticed, I have `texmf-local` in `~/tex/texmf-local`, would that make a difference? I previously renamed some folders named `.texlive2015` and `texmf`,  they were both in `~/` without me remembering creating them. Would that be a mistake?

I went through this: [Installing Emerald fonts: TeXlive won't find font files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248464/installing-emerald-fonts-texlive-wont-find-font-files) without luck.

Comment: This is a very bad phrased question with  incomplete and disconnected information  snippets. Also: If you know so little about the inner working of a tex system, why do you rename folders and move texmf-local around to non-standard locations? How should anyone not sitting before your computer now find out what you did to your system?

Comment: I renamed the main directory under installation to get a name that was easier to remember (i.e not hidden) ....

What kind of info do you want?

Comment: Minimal example, exact error message, location of all the font related files, output of kpsewhich regarding the files ...