# Why doesn't updmap-sys see the TEXMFLOCAL config?

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, installing-fonts

I tried installing emerald fonts and followed the advice in this [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248464/installing-emerald-fonts-texlive-wont-find-font-files). However, running `updmap-sys` would not update with the new fonts because it doesn't look into the file at `TEXMFLOCAL/web2c/updmap.cfg`. When I invoke it it states it will only look into the `TEXMFDIST/web2c/updmap.cfg` file. `kpsewhich --var=TEXTMFLOCAL` points to the correct directory `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.

Everything worked fine when specifying the files myself:

```
sudo updmap-sys --cnffile $(kpsewhich --var=TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg  --cnffile $(kpsewhich --var=TEXMFDIST)/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

I am on a fairly clean distribution of `texlive2015`.

Comment: How did you install TeX Live? Did you use upstream's installer or did you use a package supplied by your distro? The latter seem to sometimes remove or not create quite the same functionality as upstream.

Comment: Did you run `mktexlsr` on TEXMFLOCAL? If the file was merely created it will not be found immediately by kpathses.