# How do I use the emerald.sty font with Texlive on Windows?

Tags: fonts, texlive

I am installing on my PC under windows 10 Texlive in parallel with MikTeX.
I have a problem with a document that uses the emerald font ([emerald.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emerald)).
The error is

`File emerald.sty not found. \RequirePackage`

I tried unsuccessfully the solution given by @cfr here [Installing Emerald fonts: TeXlive won't find font files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248464/installing-emerald-fonts-texlive-wont-find-font-files):

The command given by @cfr `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` produces this error `kpsewhich: option -var is ambiguous`

So, I ran this command `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` as given in the texlive documentation here [3.7 Désinstaller la TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-fr/texlive-fr.html#x1-440003.7). I don't know if this is the correct command.

Then I wanted to use the following command `mktexlsr <TEXMFLOCAL>` as indicated by @cfr, but the syntax is not correct.

So I tried with `mktexlsr %TEXMFLOCAL%` but I got this error

```
Cannot open %TEXMFLOCAL%/ls-R to write.
mktexlsr: Done.
```

How do I use the emerald.sty font with Texlive on Windows?

Comment: May I know why you both using MikTeX and TeXLive in a system?

Comment: Since the answer is to do as shown in the duplicate question it is hard to debug " tried unsuccessfully the solution given" if you don't say what you did or what error you got.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I want to test both distros. Some say that Texlive compiles faster. I want to make up my own mind about this.

Comment: I can't check now but imho the font can be installed through tlcontrib.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have just described how I did and the errors obtained.

Comment: well it is not in tlcontrib. But if you put the files into texmfhome in the right folder it shouldn't be necessary to call mktexlsr.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I want to try, what is the exact command I need to execute?

Comment: mktexlsr and then the path.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you mean `mktexlsr %TEXMFLOCAL%` or `mktexlsr C:/texlive/texmf-local`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and `David`, kindly advise, is this advisable to use both `MikTeX` and `TeXLive` in the same computer, please

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have miktex and texlive 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019 and more older versions on my PC. For testing it is useful.