# How to input Chinese characters to LaTeX

Tags: moderncv, cjk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611/how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex)

I am a Chinese college student and I want to write a resume with LaTeX; I have the package `moderncv` but I don't know how to input Chinese characters.
Could someone give me some help please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Your question really seems to be more about how to use Chinese with LaTeX, in which case the following question is a duplicate: [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17611/2693).   On using CV packages, see [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/2693).

Answer (score 2):

`moderncv` provides a Chinese template, available for example on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template-zh.tex).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to implement this in XeLaTeX using XeCJK?

Comment: I was not aware of `XeCJK`... Is there any difference with `CJK`, other than that it works with XeLaTeX? Which of them works with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: XeCJK only works with XeLaTeX not LuaTeX. I don't think there's a CJK package that works with LuaTeX at all.  See [Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32295/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Argh, I wasn't aware of the CJK issue with Xe- and LuaTeX. Thanks!