# The IPA symbol for the labiodental flap (ⱱ)

Tags: symbols, tipa

I need the ⱱ character (prefereably with the advanced diacritic underneath it) for a phonetics paper, but the tipa package doesn't seem to contain it.  I have at least one font with this character on my computer (Charis SIL).  How do I get the character into my LaTeX document?

Comment: Do you have a lot of `tipa` characters in your document?  Could you use XeLaTeX to compile?  See e.g. [Preparing a text for conversation to LaTeX: How to convert "ejective stops" in TIPA?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116045)

Comment: There are a few - it's not an especially long paper.  How would I use XeLaTeX?  I am compiling using PDFLaTeX with TeXMaker - it's been a long while since I did anything else.

Comment: If you look at the question I linked to, there's an example of a document using phonetic symbols typed directly in the text and typeset using Charis as the font.  (The question itself isn't relevant to you, but the answer there should give you all you need.)  There are also links to two other questions about using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.  It's really quite simple.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I just didn't scroll enough.  Is compiling with XeLaTeX the same as compiling with pdfLaTeX?  Does it make a PDF, or a DVI or something?

Comment: Ok, I installed it and tried it out, and it works great, though it makes the compilation a little more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The symbol is defined as [U+2C71](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2c71/index.htm) and the advanced diacritic as [U+31F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/031f/index.htm). If you want to use some special font on you system, you will have to use `fontspec` and Lua- or XeLaTeX. I am showing two fonts I found on my system and the possible kerning correction, if the diacritic is not set nicely:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % for demo

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{quivira.otf}   
\symbol{"031F}\symbol{"2C71} \symbol{"031F}\kern-.15em\symbol{"2C71}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\symbol{"031F}\symbol{"2C71} \symbol{"031F}\kern-.12em\symbol{"2C71}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and someone answered it. Turns out you can input it as you would any Unicode character but the font needs to support it. Junicode is one such font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode} % any font that has an entry at U+2C71

\begin{document}

\char"2C71

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add the output of your example code to your post?