# Printing the character ⱱ (U+2C71 = labiodental flap)

Tags: unicode, tipa

I need to print the IPA symbol for the labiodental flap ⱱ (Unicode U+2C71) and it is not available in the `tipa` package for phonetic symbols. Is there a way I can use the Unicode hex in the input so I get the symbol as the output?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144909/the-ipa-symbol-for-the-labiodental-flap-ⱱ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use LuaLaTeX and have access to a suitable font, such as `Junicode`, you can print out the character by issuing the directive

```
\char"2C71
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode} % any font that has an entry at U+2C71
\begin{document}
\char"2C71
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then you can just enter it directly in your source (assuming you edit with a font that displays it.)

Comment: There are very few fonts that contain it: Junicode, Doulos SIL, Charis SIL and the CMU and DejaVu fonts do, but few others.

Comment: @AlanMunn - `EB Garamond` is still another font that features the character in question.

Comment: Also Free Serif, Heuristica, Erewhon, Noto Serif, Noto Sans and Fira Sans.

Comment: Also Geneva (comes with macOS) and Gentium.