# Unable to type ⱱ with tipa

Tags: fonts, symbols, linguistics, tipa

Like the title states, I am unable to find a way to type ⱱ (the voiced labiodental flap aka v with a right hook) in my document using the tipa package.

Perhaps I am just unable to find it (searched for both "ⱱ" and "voiced labiodental flap" with no results) or Rei Fukiu forgot to add it, which I cannot believe (as many other non-IPA symbols are included). I also tried different commands which I thought might work, like :v, \textrtailv, \texthtv, but none did.

Can you help me out? Thanks

Comment: It seems that it is not part of TIPA. But I wouldn't recommend using TIPA any more, really. Instead use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and an OpentType  font that contains the glyph (Doulos SIL or Charis SIL are two good phonetic fonts). See [How to use phonetic IPA characters in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542)

Comment: I think here you will get your answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414821/printing-the-character-%e2%b1%b1-u2c71-labiodental-flap

Comment: TIPA's last update was in 2004 and this character was added in the IPA chart in 2005, so obviously it is missing in that package. You can try using a new package [tipauni](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni). It has two commands for the character that you want namely `\labdentflap` and `\textipa{\*v}`. This package will produce your entire IPA in Unicode, kindly go through the documentation for further details.