# Why doesn't my italics work?

Tags: xetex, italic

Why doesn't my XeLaTeX document turn this word into italics? I simply can't figure it out.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\emph{hi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\usepackage{fontspec}` works for me.

Comment: You should never load the `inputenc` package with XeTeX or LuaTeX. You should also not likely be loading the `fontenc` package unless you know what you're doing.  Use `fontspec`  instead.  See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Looks like the basis of an answer to me :-)

Answer (score 11):

Let's see *why* it doesn't work.

The `mla` package says `\usepackage{times}` (which is *not* recommended), so that the default font family is, in LaTeX jargon, `ptm`, which corresponds to Times.

However, the Times font family that's chosen in this way has *no* version for the T2A encoding (that is, for Cyrillic), so when you typeset your document you get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ptm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 10.
```

Since no font in the T2A (Cyrillic) encoding is defined for the `ptm` family, LaTeX switches to the default. This happens at `\begin{document}. Later, when`\emph` is found, the following message is issued

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ptm/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

and the reason is just the same: no T2A encoded italic font exists in the T2A family. Since `T2A/ptm/m/n` has already been defined as an alias for `T2A/cmr/m/n`, you get upright shape.

If you want to use the standard Computer Modern fonts for your document, just say, after `\usepackage{mla}`,

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

and *don't* use XeLaTeX. With `pdflatex` you must remember to add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

if you want to input cyrillic characters directly (or use another input encoding for cyrillic).

With XeLaTeX you don't load `fontenc` and `inputenc`. And you have to use `fontspec` to choose a system font with cyrillic glyphs coverage.

### Update

There is nowadays a Times-like font that supports Cyrillic encodings, in particular T2A, also for `pdflatex`. The package is called `tempora`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage{tempora} % override \usepackage{times} of mla

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\singlespacing

\begin{document}
\emph{hi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you see a reference to “cyrillic” in the question? It is about _italics_.

Comment: @PointedEars `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` seems pretty clear, doesn't it? What do you think is the T2A encoding for?

Comment: @PointedEars You're free to downvote, if you deem so. But, please, read the whole answer before doing it. Do you think the diagnosis depends on the “cyrillic question”? It's about encodings, missing fonts and font substitutions.

Comment: I did not realize that T2A was a reference to Cyrillic. Unfortunately impossible to remove the downvote before the next edit. Perhaps you should make that part more clear, because I am not using Cyrillic and I have the same problem with XeTeX and LuaTeX, never had it with pdfLaTeX. Will RTFM.

Comment: @PointedEars Maybe now it's clearer. I also added an update about using Tempora instead of Times.

Answer (score 8):

You should never load the `inputenc` package with XeTeX or LuaTeX. You should also not likely be loading the `fontenc` package unless you know what you're doing. Use the `fontspec` package instead. See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736/2693) for more details.