# Trying to use biblatex-historian with a BibTeX backend and XeLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, xetex

I'm currently working with a large bibliography that I've assembled for my PhD studies that I've edited in several different programs (KBibTeX, JabRef, and ebib from emacs primarily) and that was annoyingly rendered non-compliant with unicode by KBibTeX (I think). This means that I can only compile documents referencing it with XeLaTeX. I'm okay with this, and I'm not even sure it's relevant to the problem I'm having.

The problem is that when I compile the document with this header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=mla, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{General}
```

it works, but once I change it to `bibstyle=historian`, it can't find the document. I am running the standard Arch Linux package of TexLive, with the package including the Historian package installed. Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: You can't use `inputenc` with XeTeX.  See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736).  Also, `bibtex` can't really deal with a UTF-8 encoded bibliography, so you will need to use `biber` as your backend. Unfortunately this may also entail installing an up-to-date TeXLive system.  See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) on this matter.

Comment: @AlanMunn The Arch repos have TL12 in. So that isn't an issue.

Comment: `biblatex-historian` is, unfortunately, woefully out of date.  It stands at version 0.4, which was released for version v.0.9b.  `biblatex` is now at version 2.6 (I'm actually still only using 2.5).  So I would check your versions; it may be that your version of `biblatex` is too new to be used completely successfully with `biblatex-historian`.

Answer (score 2):

You are providing only a spare information. However there are some mistakes:

- If you compile with XeLaTeX you need not load `inputenc`. See: [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex)
- `biblatex` offers another command to load the bibliography database. Instead of `\bibliography` use `\addbibresource` whereby the extension of the file is needed.
- The style `historian` requires the package `csquotes`.

Based on this information your header should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=mla, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{General.bib}
```

---

Here a MWE:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
 %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=historian,maxbibnames=6,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What version(s) does this work with?  With `biblatex` 2.5 (using either `biber` [v1.5] or `bibtex`), e.g., it doesn't.  My output is: Knuth, Donald E. *The TEXbook*. Volume A **volumeof** *Computers & Typesetting*. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1984.

Comment: @jon: You are getting an output. The rest depends on the OP ;-)