# Accessing TeX token or exporting filtered plain text

Tags: luatex, tex-core, context, parsing, lua

(*updated according to gained information*)

In the context of keyword extraction from arbitrary (La)TeX documents and simple manipulations with them (automated annotation), I would like to be able to do the following things:

1. Access a stream of tokens with information required to build tree-like representation (i.e., I need to know when environment starts, when it ends, when math formula occurs)
2. Export plain text representation of the document while being able to filter out commands (for example, remove equations or some sections).

I already have a very complicated LaTeX parser written in C++, but still I am unable to avoid the problem of expansion of commands.

Basically, if an author defines a command `\keyword` that just prints `keyword`, I cannot deal with this in a general manner. (And people really do that and tend to do this with the most important keywords!)

So, on one hand I need to get a plain text representation of the document while filtering out the math statements and not loosing information about position of the commands and environments (to aid sentence tokenizer and keyword extractor).

On the other hand, having an arbitrary TeX document I need to find a node with a specific word in it, manipulate it (remove/replace/wrap in a link) and then compile the document.

I vaguely understand that this should be possible using LuaTeX or ConTeXt, but I wasn't able to find accessible examples on LuaTeX wiki.

---

**Update:** I think I need to clarify that I cannot control the incoming documents, so the goal is to analyse and manipulate arbitrary valid LaTeX code.

**Bounty update:** Existing answer provides lots of valuable information about achieving my goals with writing input documents in ConTeXt, which is unfortunately inapplicable

**Bounty update 2:** To provide you the scale: we need to process more than a million documents and the number is increasing.

Comment: you would have to define some tree structure, TeX doesn't build anything approximating an AST representation that you could access

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true, I understand that TeX does not function in this way. But by a stream of different tokens and state switches I can build such a tree. Anyhow, AST is how I do things now, but this is not the only way

Comment: (sorry) "On the other hand,.....then compile the document." . This should be possible in luatex/context mkiv --- if I have understood you correctly.
See  luatex manual
https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php/tags/0.95.0/manual/?root=luatex
and the context mailing list.

Comment: @LuigiScarso, I have found the following approaches on the LuaTeX wiki: http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Traversing_tokens and http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Traversing_TeX_nodes , but they seem to be really low level (i.e., at the stage of TeX source scanning) and occur before the command expansion. Am I wrong? Do you know of a way to access compound tokens like words, not symbols?

Comment: there are no compound tokens like words in tex, there are just sequences of character tokens at the token level or sequences of character/glyph nodes in a horizontal list in a box.  Of the lua callbacks you mention, the node one is necessarily after expansion. For doing weird replacement effects to text in lualatex look at the chickenize package which has examples of the (ab)use of many of the callbacks into luatex's node structure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, it looks amazingly close to my goal! From the questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21736/using-xelatex-instead-of-pdflatex is see that it is possible to compile LaTeX documents using other engines with some automatable effort. But will then LuaTeX features work as expected? I.e., there is an answer by Aditya below, but it relies on the specific syntax of LuaTeX/ConTeXt

Comment: @AndriiMagalich Please accept my apologies if I'm mistaken, but you seem to be confusing different engines with different formats. These are very different kettles of tofu! In most cases, it is relatively straightforward to switch to a different engine e.g. from pdfTeX to LuaTeX or TeX to XeTeX or XeTeX to LuaTeX or whatever. There can be complications, but, for many, many documents, these will be trivial or relatively minor. To switch from one format to another typically requires translating all the formatting and structure of the document. Moreover, this cannot always be done in any ...

Comment: ... systematic way because the macros etc. for mark-up provided by one format do not map one-one onto those provided by another format. Or even approximately one-one. And that is before considering additional packages (in LaTeX) or macros (in plain etc.). Switching to LuaTeX should be relatively straightforward: LuaLaTeX is still LaTeX. Switching to ConTeXt (or plain or Lollipop or...) is a different story. For that you'd need to consider how to implement the current document mark-up in the target format.

Comment: I don't understand your question so maybe my comments completely miss the mark. But your last comment seemed to be running together switch-to-LuaTeX and switch-to-ConTeXt. Those are very different hurdles.

Comment: @cfr Thank you. My hope was that LuaTeX or ConTeXt would provide access to internals of TeX and I would be able to intercept the intermediate representation of the document which is already parsed and partially expanded. I did not know much about those systems before asking

Comment: I don't know what you mean about providing access to the internals of TeX. You don't need a specific engine (LuaTeX) or a different format (ConTeXt) for that. I don't know what an AST is, but the problem is not that LaTeX doesn't provide access to it whereas ConTeXt does. The problem is that no such structure exists when you use LaTeX (or plain). What you're calling the `intermediate representation` isn't there. You are asking as if the problem is how to access X, but the problem you are trying to solve is the non-existence of X. In ConTeXt, the format is providing X. The LaTeX format doesn't.

Comment: @cfr AST is the Abstract Syntax Tree, which TeX lacks. So I removed it from the question. But I still need to obtain comparable information. TeX has to parse the document somehow and at some point it decides when something is inside of something else — this is what I need

Comment: I'm not sure it does, but @DavidCarlisle would know.

Comment: @AndriiMagalich no really it never knows that, it does not parse the document in advance it interleaves tokenisation, and execution so has usually only read as far as the next line, so is executing the content of an environment before it has seen the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this is fine, because then one can just write down the events of entering and exiting environments. Is it than possible get plain text (with expanded commands!) of a chunk of a document inside some environment?

Comment: @AndriiMagalich that is what the existing convertors such as tex4ht or latexml (probably try that first) do, but for example if someone goes `\def\keyword{hello}\keyword` I would expect all such convertors to make that indistinguishable from `hello` isn't that what you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, this is very relevant. I summarized what I've found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314927/106999

Answer (score 14):

In ConTeXt, one option is to export your document as XML. You can then manipulate the resulting XML document using standard XML tools in your favourite programming language.

As an example, consider this example:

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\setupinteraction[state=start]

\starttext
\startsection[title={Test of export}]
  This is to test how \CONTEXT\ export works. First, we input a test file
  below.

  \startnarrower
    \input ward
  \stopnarrower

 Let's see some other environments, such as\footnote{Note that we define a
 float in \in{Figure}[fig:mill].}

  \startitemize[n]
    \item A table:

      \startTABLE
        \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC \NR
        \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC \NR
        \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 3 \NC \NR
      \stopTABLE

    \item A formula

      \startformula
        α^2 + β^2 = 2
      \stopformula

    \item A figure

      \externalfigure[mill.png][width=5cm]

  \stopitemize

  \startplacefigure
      [title={This is a Mill}, reference={fig:mill}]
    \externalfigure[mill.png][width=5cm]
  \stopplacefigure

\stopsection
\stoptext
```

and process it using `context filename`. This will create a directory `\jobname-export` with the following structure:

```
\jobname-export
|
+-- images
|   +--- <image file1>
|   +---- ....
+-- style
|   +-- \jobname-defaults.css
|   +-- \jobname-images.css
|   +-- \jobname-styles.css
|   +-- \jobname-template.css
+-- \jobname-div.xhtml
+-- \jobname-pub.lua
+-- \jobname-raw.xml
+-- \jobname-tag.xhtml
```

Out of these, the **`\jobname-raw.xml`** contains the AST of the complete document. For the above document it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<!--

    input filename   : test
    processing date  : Tue Jun 14 19:58:26 2016
    context version  : 2016.06.02 21:28
    exporter version : 0.34

-->

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles/test-defaults.css" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles/test-images.css" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styles/test-styles.css" ?>

<document date="Tue Jun 14 19:58:26 2016" file="test" context="2016.06.02 21:28" language="en" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" version="0.34">
 <metadata>
 </metadata>
 <section detail="section" chain="section" implicit="1" level="3">
  <sectionnumber>1</sectionnumber>
   <sectiontitle>Test of export</sectiontitle>
  <sectioncontent>
This is to test how ConTEXt export works. First, we input a test file below.
   <break/>
The Earth, as a habitat for animal life, is in old age and has a fatal illness. Several, in fact. It would be happening whether humans had ever evolved or not. But our presence is like the effect of an old-age patient who smokes many packs of cigarettes per day <subsentencesymbol symbol="middle">—</subsentencesymbol> and we humans are the cigarettes.
   <break/>
Let’s see some other environments, such as<descriptionsymbol detail="footnote" insert="1"><sup>1</sup></descriptionsymbol> 
   <itemgroup detail="itemize" chain="itemize" level="1" symbol="n">
    <item>
     <itemtag>1.</itemtag>
     <itemcontent>A table:<table><tablerow><tablecell align="flushleft"> 1 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 2 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 3 </tablecell></tablerow><tablerow><tablecell align="flushleft"> 1 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 2 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 3 </tablecell></tablerow><tablerow><tablecell align="flushleft"> 1 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 2 </tablecell><tablecell align="flushleft"> 3 </tablecell></tablerow></table></itemcontent>
    </item>
    <item>
     <itemtag>2.</itemtag>
     <itemcontent>A formula<formula> <formulacontent><m:math display="block" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><m:mrow><m:msup><m:mi></m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup><m:mo>+</m:mo><m:msup><m:mi></m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:mrow></m:math></formulacontent> </formula></itemcontent>
    </item>
    <item>
     <itemtag>3.</itemtag>
     <itemcontent>A figure<image width="5.000cm" height="3.750cm" id="image-1" name="mill.png" label="3.750cm"></image></itemcontent>
    </item>
   </itemgroup>
   <float detail="figure" chain="figure" implicit="4" explicit="fig:mill" reference="fig:mill">
    <floatcontent><image width="5.000cm" height="3.750cm" id="image-2" name="mill.png" label="3.750cm"></image></floatcontent>
    <floatcaption><floatlabel detail="figure">Figure </floatlabel><floatnumber detail="figure">1</floatnumber> <floattext>This is a Mill</floattext></floatcaption>
    </float>
   <description detail="footnote" chain="footnote" insert="1">
    <descriptiontag><sup>1</sup> </descriptiontag>
    <descriptioncontent>Note that we define a float in <link destination="fig:mill" location="fig:mill">Figure 1</link>.</descriptioncontent>
   </description>
  </sectioncontent>
 </section>
</document>
```

Note that the math formula has been exported to (formatted for clarity).

```
<formula> <formulacontent><m:math xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <m:mrow>
    <m:msup><m:mi></m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup>
    <m:mo>+</m:mo>
    <m:msup><m:mi></m:mi><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:msup>
    <m:mo>=</m:mo>
    <m:mn>2</m:mn>
  </m:mrow>
 </m:math></formulacontent> </formula>
```

Now, if you want, you can easily filter out the math (or any other part of the document).

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent! Do you have any knowledge regarding the reliability of this conversion? I.e., will it work with an arbitrary LaTeX document using arbitrary packages (but, of course, compilable in the environment)

Comment: This is a ConTeXt solution, so it won't work with LaTeX packages. It is relatively simple to make a new environment compatible with this export.

Comment: I see... Unfortunately, input documents are given and the whole thing is that I cannot control them.

Comment: I understand. But in your original question you had asked if this is possible in ConTeXt. I can delete my answer, if you want this question to appear unanswered so as to attract more attention from LaTeX users.

Comment: your comment is a valuable piece of information, despite it misses my goal. If you think that removing the answer will help... Anyhow, thank you for the effort.

Comment: Please don't delete.

Comment: Please retain the answer: it demonstrates it's technically doable! Most of the issue with translating to LaTeX (or plain or ...) is that ConTeXt has structures at the macro level to allow this to work: the Lua side is not the 'key' to the problem.

Comment: @JosephWright seems that it is doable only with specially prepared documents, not with any compilable TeX

Comment: @AndriiMagalich Not exactly: there's no technical reason one couldn't set the appropriate structures. The issue is that LaTeX2e doesn't really have them, sot he work required is _significant_. (I'm on the team working on LaTeX3, so I have a sense of the amount of effort to do a 'complete' job!)

Comment: @JosephWright unfortunately, I am looking for a way to avoid *significant* amount of work. We already tried to parse TeX ourselves :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little hesitant to post this as I'm not sure how adaptable it would be to your case, but with the hope that it might point you in the right direction, here it is.

I have been developing a system that allows me to write documents using LaTeX and writes output files as text files in a variety of formats.  My current primary use-case is to output HTML5 documents, with the maths as MathML.  It's very much in development and I fix the stuff that I need without paying too much attention to the "big picture" of what it might be capable of.

Anyway, a recent adaptation was to use the capabilities of LuaTeX to do the text output directly.  Previously I'd been writing to a PDF and using pdftotext to extract the text, but this was unstable.  So I played around with LuaTeX a bit and found a way to accomplish what I wanted: direct output to a text file.

The lua file that does this can be found as part of my [latex-to-internet](https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet) repository on github (ignore the README, it is vastly out of date).  The specific file is [textoutput.lua](https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet/blob/master/textoutput.lua) (there's a fair bit in there which is concerned with converting maths to MathML, I don't know if that's relevant).  You'd also need to look at lines 53 to 104 of [internettext.code.tex](https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet/blob/master/internettext.code.tex) as those install the hooks for outputting to text.

As I said, the system works for me.  All of the pages on [my website](http://loopspace.mathforge.org/) are written as fully-compilable LaTeX documents which my system converts to HTML5+MathML files (the graphics are done with TikZ, naturally).  But it would probably need some adaptation to work for your system, particularly as you have no control over the input files.

Comment: So, you inject a small snippet of code in the preambule of the document and it allows you to parse the structure of the page? Did you try this with complicated documents like scientific papers?

Comment: @AndriiMagalich It's a bit more complicated than that.  The system was written for me to use and I don't really care about mass translating documents so I didn't write it for that.  I just wanted to show an example of getting TeX to do some processing and get text output.

Comment: I am just curious, why not use tex4ht? Since you say `My current primary use-case is to output HTML5 documents, with the maths as MathML`, could not tex4ht be used for this? Just asking, that is all. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser That's a good question, comment prob a bit short for a full answer. First, html wasn't my initial goal. I was originally using it to author articles for other formats such as Markdown and its many derivatives. I wrote blog posts for the TeX blog using it, for example. Second, I found I wanted more control over the detail than tex4ht could easily give me. Rather than trying to get a webpage to look like a pdf, I wanted to be able to easily control different aspects of the webpage by configuring the document accordingly. tex4ht seemed too much like a black box for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

### Partial solution for XML export

In the case of information retrieval, @DavidCarlisle [advised](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312587/accessing-tex-token-or-exporting-filtered-plain-text?noredirect=1#comment768295_312587) me to take a look at LaTeXML. On the website of the project I have found a link to an outdated [experiment](http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/) on exporting ~730k scientific preprints from [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org) into XML format. This experiment ended in 2013, but at that moment

```
Result                  count   %
-------------------------------------
none                    0       0.00
incomplete              40575   5.80
complete with errors    234047  33.46
success                 424800  60.74
-------------------------------------
```

i.e., only 60% papers pass. Most of the errors are the missing macros and I cannot tell immediately whether this can be fixed.

arXiv is one of my sources of articles, so this is very relevant. Looks like this is not a practical thing, but definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: you may also look at tex4ht, which supports most LaTeX packages and it is highly configurable, so it is easy to add support for missing commands and environments

Comment: @michal.h21 thanks, David mentioned it as well, but I haven't looked at it yet. I looks really rusty

Comment: it is not user friendly at first sight, but it is powerful and it has extensive infrastructure for custom configuration

Comment: 60% strikes me as very good, considering. However, note that arXiv does *not* accept just any valid LaTeX source. So there's going to be a partial standardisation effect as people have to made their code compliant in order to get it accepted.Neither can teX4ht manage all valid LaTeX, although it does extremely well. It may look 'really rusty' to you - it is not currently maintained - but it is better than any of the other converters I've tried.